# how to refresh listview wampserver

Tags: android, wamp

i'm trying to develop application that have a list of user that takes from database i have problem to **refresh** the listview:

```
void list(){    

try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://*******/login/test.php");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValue = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValue));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
   }

//convert
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
     sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
     String line="0";
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
      }is.close();
      result=sb.toString();
      }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
      }

//jonson
String username;
try{
      jArray = new JSONArray(result);
      JSONObject json_data=null;
      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             username=json_data.getString("username");
             items.add(username);
          SP.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));

         }

      }

      catch(JSONException e1){
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the adapter you have `notifyDataSetChanged()`

instead of :

```
SP.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));
```

you should do

```
 SP.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After each added item, or after all items has been added